# Minimal linearly dependent subset

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is linearly dependent and does not contain the zero vector, then there is a minimal linearly dependent subset $C \subseteq A$ such that $C$ is linearly dependent and any proper subset of $C$ is linearly independent.

I need some help writing the proof for this assignment. We know that for each $x \in A$ the set $\{x\}$ is lin.independent. So if we add to this set elements of $A$ that are not linear combinations of $x$ or the others we will be able to form a maximal linearly dependent set. Afterwards we need to add another element to get to $C$.

Is my approach correct? Do i need to use induction to formulate the proof?